# What does おくれ mean in this context?

Tags: verbs

> それでは、このお金をあげるから、おじさんにカメを売って**おくれ**

What does おくれ mean in this context? What is this verb form?

Answer (score 11):

「くれ」 is the imperative form of 「くれる」　and the 「お」 is the honorific.

> 「Verb in te-form + おくれ」 = "Do ~~ for me / to me."

Without the 「お」, it would sound much less friendly.

「おくれ」 is used much more often in fiction than in real life -- at least in real, present-day life.

> "Now, I'll give you this money; (Please) sell me the turtle."

Comment: Are you sure this is not simply the imperative of おくる?

Comment: @user54609: That is very unlikely because a plain imperative is rather rude and does not match the rest of the sentence.  This is the same reason as why それでは、このお金をあげるから、おじさんにカメを売れ would be wierd.

Comment: @user54609 I am more than sure.  What are you even talking about?   Who would ever say 「売って送れ！」 to a kid or anyone else for that matter?  て、何年後に応答してんねん！

Comment: Is くれ really imperative, or is it rather the stem, as in おくれなさい?