# Struggling to parse last section of 「あんた　子どもたちを　森へ　すててきておくれ」

Tags: verbs, compound-verbs

The sentence is from [a Japanese telling of Hansel and Gretel](http://www.firegrubs.com/images/chokochoko/pdf/readingarticle0027.pdf) and I know enough to read it as "Leave your children in the forest before it is too late."

What I don't understand here is how すてる has been modified by きておくれ. What does that き relate to? Is it part of すててき to change (discard) somehow or is it something like (leave)(come here)(without delay)?

Comment: Please see http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/difference-between-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F-and-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B and the linked questions on the right hand side.

Comment: おくれ here is not related to 遅れる【おくれる】 "to be late", but rather to the imperative くれ (similar to ください) prefixed with honorific お-. See also: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13334/

Comment: @Earthliŋ I have no idea what I'm looking for on that link. Can't see how いく maps to きて.

Comment: @senshin So if おくれ is the imperative, what does きて mean?

Comment: @SimonGill すててきて is parsed as [す]{捨}てて + [き]{来}て and we have a bunch of questions about this structure, so I linked it here in case you're interested. すててくる literally means something like "go throw away and come back", so as per the question senshin linked すててきておくれ "Please go and cast [our children] away (and then come back)"

Comment: @Earthliŋ I know it's noddy, but would you mind turning your comment that reminded me about the verb irregularity of くる into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments, you should parse すててきておくれ as すてて + きて + おくれ.

- Without changing the content or function you can replace おくれ by ください (more about おくれ [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13337/1628))、
- すてて is the te-form of すてる (here) "to cast away",
- きて is the te-form of くる "to come [back]",
- Xてくる is a common construction of saying "to go, do X [and then return]", but as indicated you might not necessarily translate the くる as "return"
- Xてください is the construction for phrasing a request "Please do X"

> すてて + きて + ください
>   Please go cast away [the children] [and come back when you're done]