# meaning of "おくる" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, verbs

I just listened to 高気圧ガール by Tatsuro Yamashita and I came across **連れておくれ** for the first time. So I was just wondering what role the **おくれ** part plays here.

First verse for context:

> なめらかな白い 砂は 溜息の 照り返し
>
> しなやかな南風は 舞い上がる 長い 髪
>
> 2000マイル飛び越えて 迎えに 来たのさ
>
> "Come with me"
>
> 連れて行っておくれどこまでも

Comment: This isn't おくる. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13334/what-does-%e3%81%8a%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8c-mean-in-this-context

Comment: thanks for replying so quickly☺